# How to style a div like the button-element?

Tags: html, css, button

I've noticed that when using the `<button></button>` element, the browsers will naturally assume that you want to center the inline content, and that the element is clickable. Is it possible to have a div behave in the same way through css? I went through the UA-stylesheet to see if I could figure it out, but nothing made it center it vertically.

The only other way i know to get the same result is with 2 divs. One wrapper with `display: table`, and a div with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.

But that creates an extra div. Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour with just one element?

Thanks.

Comment: ***extra div*** or ***extra element*** is always a normal need/requirement for many advanced features in HTML/CSS. So it's totally acceptable.

Comment: You can do it if you are ok using set heights. Also line height will help. But if you do not know the width/height of your content, or it varies alot then you would have to alter this potentially.

Comment: Im not okay with set height, thats part of the problem that is solved with the button element.

Comment: @kingking: I know, and i am. But since the button element is already capable of getting around this it should be possible to do it on a normal div? But i guess form elements has special behaviour, that can't be replicated?.

Comment: @MaltheMilthers of course 1 div can't have the same functionality, the point is what you see is what the **browser** does **internally**, the `button` is designed to be rendered like that but `div` is not.

Answer (score 14):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Sj4A/3/ - this does center vertically and horizontally (just added `text-align: center;` to the originally answer)

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#444;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#DDD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
div:active {
    color:red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Comment: `buttons` do not have a `max-width` ;)

Comment: Its not centered vertically is it? if you add a height to that div, the content is still at top? or am i missing something? vertical-align does not work in inline-blocks does it?

Comment: correction.. vertical-align does not affect the contents of inline-blocks. thats only table-cells? right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Sj4A/4/ - `display: table-cell;` should sort the vertical align

Answer (score 2):

You don't need multiple divs, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3h3tpo5/), it's a single DIV that looks and behaves like a button.

the HTML:

```
<div class='btn'>
  this looks like a button
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;

    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

If you want the button to actually link to something (behave like a link), simply change your HTML to this:

```
<a href='test.html' class='btn'>
  this looks like a button
</a>
```

If you use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) you don't have to define the .btn class, it's included in that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are asking the wrong question.

It may be simpler to give your button a class and then ensure the inline content is styled as you want.

Anything that you can put in a DIV, you should be able to put in a button.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, don't you think so?

Comment: A bit of both :-). Styling a button would probably result in less custom CSS than the other answer here, as the baseline is closer to what is needed.

Comment: I know i could just use the button element, but since you can make divs behave like tables, I was hoping i could make them behave as buttons too. Gives me more sematic freedom :) feels weird to add cursor properties to an element to get rid of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can center the content of a divby adding the same amount amount of padding on each side.

```
padding:2px 10px;
```

This adds 2px to the top and bottom and 10px to the left and right, thus centering the content in the div.

I also styled the rest of the div to look and behave like a `button`. Looks are based on Firefox's default `<button>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/evSb5/2/

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly like the button type input

```
#divbut {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #444;
    background: #232323;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    border-top: solid 2px #767676;
    border-left: solid 2px #767676;
    border-right: 2px #777171;
    border-bottom: 2px #777171;
    border-style: outset;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

#divbut:active {
    color: green;
    border-top: 2px solid #777171;
    border-left: 2px solid #777171;
    border-right: solid 2px #767676;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #767676;
    border-style: inset;
}

<div id="divbut" class="center">
    <span class="unselectable">Button</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

css:

```
div.button {
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance:button;
  padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;
  font-size:13px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:context-menu;
}
```

html:

```
<div role="button" class="button">Press Me!</div>
```

This gets you as close as I could get to a real button.

For anything other than Chrome: look up `appearance`.  Actually, just use Chrome... :)