# <div> and <button> different acting with identical styles

Tags: html, css, button

Button and div acts differently with the same styles. Actual difference in width: div have 100% of parent width, while button acting like `display: inline;` with minimal width, no actual inlining. And both have `display: block;`.

That strange button behavior is what I'm trying to achieve with div. Problem is that `'width: auto;'` works in another way. So I'm gave div's same style as button have by default in chrome. As a result there is one property sets differently: `-webkit-appearance`, but changing it make no sense for width or display property.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/requiemonline/pen/RvMLoL)

Also I'm tried to achieve that with `display: flex;`, but width becomes 100%.
If there's another way do achieve this, it have to deal with parent `height: 0px` and `display: absolute`

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @DCR What's the reason of such different behavior and how to make div elements width minimize as button elements width does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a div like the button-element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608346/how-to-style-a-div-like-the-button-element)

Comment: @A.Meshu that question is about centering, unfortunately, there's no answer of mine.

Answer (score 0):

A button is displayed as inline-block.  If you want a div to 'act' the same way
display the div as an inline-block as well.  As to why buttons behave this way
see the following post:

[button behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764122/button-is-an-inline-element-but-width-is-working)

```css
div{
border:black solid ;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<button></button>

<div>x</div>
```

Comment: With `display: inline-block;` all elements aligns in one line while I'm need them in column with minimal width.

Comment: Linked post makes things cleaner for me,  but propblem staying unsolved.